# Unhide "Run & Debug" option in activity bar of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have accidently Hide the "Run & Debug" option in activity bar of visual studio code. How to "Unhide" that option in activity bar?

Comment: right click on the activity bar

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Right click</kbd> the activity bar and re-tick the `Run and Debug` box.

[image]

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, to temporarily open the menu.

Answer (score 0):

press **cltr** + **shift**+ **D** for temporarily open the menu.
Then Right click on the **Run and Debug** icon then click on **Keep 'Run and Debug**'